# Font Smoothing in WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, internet-explorer, browser

Here is text rendered in a WPF WebBrowser control:

[image]

Here is the same text using the same font rendered in IE10 on the same machine:

[image]

I have tried the registry hack to make the WebBrowser control use the latest IE as expained here: 
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version
It doesn't help.

The OS is Windows 7

How can I make my WPF WebBrowser Control do font smoothing.

Comment: Have you tried in your Web Broswser xaml : **RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"** ?

Comment: @cvraman I have now and no it doesn't help

Comment: what dose version inistaled in target os?IE8?

Comment: @IRSOG as the question says the OS is running IE10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it!

Setting the registry makes the browser use the latest CSS and javascript, however fixing the font rendering required adding the following to the header of the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE10">
```

I'm not sure why this should be necessary, seems like the registry hack should be sufficient but it isn't.

Comment: The value "IE10" is incorrect, in my case (Win10) it falls back to IE 8, which is the same as if there is this meta tag missing. For true IE10 it's "IE=10", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/1053562. The smoothing difference is between IE=8 (less blurry) and IE=9 onwards (more blurry). With "IE10" I had issues with scrollbar (always visible, unstylable), which isn't present with "IE=8" (visible only when needed, stylable by CSS).